# How to handle fade transition in Cypress?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress, timeout

I have a popup with the class ".fade"

```
<div class="modal fade employee" id="employeeFormModal" />
```

It has the following CSS attributes:

```
.fade {
    transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
}

.fade:not(.show) {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

When a button is clicked, the popup will close. The test code is as follows:

```
cy.get('button[class*="save"]').click();

// cy.wait(5000) will do the trick 
cy.get("#employeeFormModal").should("be.visible");

cy.get("#employeeFormModal").should("not.be.visible");
```

The problem is that both `should("be.visible")` and `should("not.be.visible")` pass, which suggests that the `#employeeFormModal` is simultaneously both visible and not visible.

I suspected there might be a timing issue due to the fade transition, so I added `cy.wait()` after the `click()` command with a period longer than 0.15s. Subsequently, the `.should("be.visible")` assertion failed, which is what I expected.

My question is:
**Is there a better way to handle the fade transition effect without having to wait for a specific amount of time?** (like what I did `cy.wait(5000)`)

Comment: See [Animations](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements#Animations) - ***Cypress will automatically determine if an element is animating and wait until it stops***

Answer (score 2):

***simultaneously both visible and not visible*** would only apply if `defaultCommandTimeout` was set to 0.

But each command retries for whatever timeout is set (default 4 seconds) so

```js
cy.get("#employeeFormModal").should("not.be.visible")
```

initially fails and retries the whole chain (get() and should()) until it passes.

To see the retry calls, use callback version of `should()`

```js
cy.get('button[class*="save"]').click();
cy.get("#employeeFormModal").should('be.visible');

cy.get("#employeeFormModal")
  .should($el => {
    const isVisible = $el.is(':visible') 
    console.log(isVisible)                      // initially true, changes to false
    assert(!isVisible, 'Element is not visible')
})
```